# A closure of associated points as a support of an element of $m \in M$ where $M$ is a finitely generated $A$ module

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring and $M$ a finitely generated $A$ module.
>   Suppose $p_1, p_2, p_3 \in Ass (M)$, some associated primes of $M$
>   such that $p_i = ann (m_i)$. I wanted to show that there exists $m \in M$
>   such that Supp $m = \bigcup_{i=1}^3 V(p_i)$.

I would appreciate any hint. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $(0)=N_1\cap\cdots\cap N_n$ a reduced primary decomposition of $(0)$ (in $M$), and $p_i=r_M(N_i)$. Set  $N=N_4\cap\cdots\cap N_n$. Pick an element $m\in N-N_1\cup N_2\cup N_3$ and you are done.

Why there is such an element? Suppose the contrary, that is, $N\subseteq N_1\cup N_2\cup N_3$ and let $x_i\in N-N_i$ for $i=1,2,3$. We also have $p_2\cap\cdots\cap p_n\not\subset p_1$, so there is $a_1\in p_2\cap\cdots\cap p_n- p_1$. Analogously chose $a_2,a_3$. There is $k_1\ge 1$ such that $a_1^{k_1}M\subseteq N_2\cap\cdots\cap N_n$, and similarly $k_2$ and $k_3$. Now set $m=\sum_{i=1}^3a_i^{k_i}x_i$.

Comment: The above answer shows that given a finite *reduced* set of primary submodules, then any intersection of some of them is not contained into the union of the others. (The first interesting case occurs when consider the intersection of all but three of them.) For primary ideals this is trivial.

Comment: Nice! This is a common technique and nice to see it appearing again.